# Find a value that gives the local maximum of a function that takes two input variables

Tags: r, optimization, maximization

I asked a similar question earlier but my question wasn't clear. Here's another attempt.

Suppose you have the following function that takes two inputs, a and b.

```
inputs <- c(a, b)

y <- function(inputs) {
  a <- inputs[1]
  b <- inputs[2]
  output <- a/100 * (20 * b)^0.8 + (100 - a) / 100 * (10 * (100 - b))^0.8
  return(output)
}
```

For all possible values of a in the range [0, 100], I want to find the value of b that maximizes the output of the function above, with the restriction that b also has to be a value in the range [0, 100].

In other words, I want to plot b as a function of a, such that b maximizes the output value of the function above for the given value of a.

How would you write the code for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would rewrite the function as a function of two parameters, by this order, `b` and `a`. This is because R base function `optimize` optimizes on its first argument. From the documentation:

> The function `optimize` searches the interval from lower to upper for a
>   minimum or maximum of the function `f` with respect to its first
>   argument.

The default is to minimize, to maximize set the respective argument to `TRUE`.
Then, in order to maximize for values of `a` in the interval `[0, 100]` run the optimization function for a sequence of `a` values. The result is stored in a list, coerced to data.frame and plotted.

```
y <- function(b, a) {
  output <- a/100 * (20 * b)^0.8 + (100 - a) / 100 * (10 * (100 - b))^0.8
  output
}

a <- seq(0, 100, by = 0.1)
max_list <- lapply(a, function(.a){
  optimize(y, interval = c(0, 100), .a, maximum = TRUE, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5)
})

max_data <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, max_list)
row.names(max_data) <- NULL
head(max_data)
#       maximum objective
#1 9.302363e-09  251.1886
#2 9.302363e-09  250.9375
#3 9.302363e-09  250.6863
#4 9.302363e-09  250.4351
#5 9.302363e-09  250.1839
#6 9.302363e-09  249.9327


plot(objective ~ maxima, max_data)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  It was very helpful.  Could you tell me what the "." does in the function inside the lapply function? max_list <- lapply(a, function(.a){

Comment: @johnc It makes a different name, nothing more. The loop is on `a` so I prefer to call the loop variable `.a`. it could have been any other name.